# Printing PDF doc to esc/pos Thermal printer

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, thermal-printer, escpos

We are developing a POS APP using xamarin.forms, in that we need to print the receipt to an esc/pos thermal printer connected via LAN. 
We have multi language support with the App, printing multiple language with the esc/pos commands by changing code page works perfectly.
But its working for some supported language only, for other language its printing garbage characters(unreadable ones).

so we thought of creating a pdf for the receipt and print that one. we tried to create the pdf and then convert to bitmap and then send to the printer by using esc pos commands, but its not printing anything.

```
    public BitImage(String filename)
    {
        Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(filename);
        var pdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(ParcelFileDescriptor.Open(file, ParcelFileMode.ReadOnly));
        PdfRenderer.Page page = pdfRenderer.OpenPage(0);
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(page.Width, page.Height, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
        page.Render(bmp, null, null, PdfRenderMode.ForPrint);
        load(bmp);
    }


private void load(Bitmap bmp)
{
    int w = bmp.Width;
    int h = bmp.Height;

    int bw = (w + 7) / 8;
    if (bw > 255)
        bw = 255;

    int bh = h / 8;
    if (bh > 24)
    {
        bh = 24;
    }

    initData(bw * 8, bh * 8);

    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
        {
            if (bmp.GetPixel(x, y) == Color.Black)
                setPixel(x, y);
        }
    }
}

private void initData(int w, int h)
{
    width = w;
    height = h;
    pitch = h / 8;
    data = new byte[w * pitch];
}

private void setPixel(int x, int y)
{
    if (x >= width || y >= height)
    {
        return;
    }
    int mask = (0x0080 >> (y % 8));
    data[(x * pitch) + (y / 8)] |= (byte)mask;
}


public void PrintData() 
{
    byte[] CMD_INIT = { 0x1B, 0x40 };
    byte[] CMD_UPLOAD_IMAGE = { 0x1D, 0x2A, 0, 0 };
    byte[] CMD_PRINT_IMAGE = { 0x1D, 0x2F, 0 };
    byte[] CMD_CUT = { 0x1D, 0x56, 0x01 };
    CMD_UPLOAD_IMAGE[2] = (byte)(width / 8);
    CMD_UPLOAD_IMAGE[3] = (byte)(height / 8);

    #region Print Via Lan
    Socket pSocket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
    pSocket.SendTimeout = 1500;
    pSocket.Connect("192.168.15.168", 9100);
    pSocket.Send(CMD_INIT);
    pSocket.Send(CMD_UPLOAD_IMAGE);
    pSocket.Send(data);
    pSocket.Send(CMD_PRINT_IMAGE);
    pSocket.Send(CMD_CUT);
    pSocket.Close();
    #endregion
}
```

Please help me, whether i am doing it in correct way? 
or is there any better way to do the same?

Comment: this is probably highly dependent on the specific printer you are using.  If it works perfectly with some languages but not others, I would contact the manufacturer for support

Comment: @Jason Thanks for your reply. Some language is not printing is because of the printer is not supporting that Languages.
because of this only I tried to print the pdf instead of the Text. You have any idea about how to print the pdf?

Comment: I think the general approach you're using might work, but the print density will be a lot lower than the display density which could cause a problem.  Have you verified that the pdf and bitmap are both valid?  Is the PDF even necessary - could you not just create the bitmap directly from the screen?

Comment: I created the pdf using itext and I can open and view it. Also I used TallComponents.PDF.Rasterizer for converting pdf to bitmap also I can see the bitmap via Imageview. So i think the pdf and bitmap are valid.

pdf is not neccessary, I tried to generate bitmap from my listview but I didn't find anything for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use libraries like SkiaSharp to make Image/PDF from your data in any language and print them properly using any printer.

I've created a sample to demonstrate how to print images properly with ESC\POS printers in C#: [GitHub code repo](https://github.com/MoienTajik/EscPrinterSample)